# Using 'compact' - possible issues

Tags: ruby

My code takes text as input, splits it in single characters, and then returns an array, where words are grouped, and non-word characters are separate items.
First variant:

```
def make_array(text)
  @raw_array=text.split(//)
  @result_array=[]
k=0
for i in 0...@raw_array.length
if @raw_array[i]=~/[\W]/
@result_array[k+1]=@raw_array[i]
k+=2
else
@result_array[k]='' if @result_array[k]==nil
@result_array[k]=@result_array[k]+@raw_array[i]
end
end
  print @result_array.inspect
end
```

when input has non-characters one-by-one, it also causes nil items in array

```
make_array("TEST TEST TEST TEST")#=>["TEST", " ", "TEST", " ", "TEST", " ", "TEST"]
make_array("TEST,,, TEST TEST TEST")#=>["TEST", ",", nil, ",", nil, ",", nil, ...]
```

I can just use compact method, and then

```
make_array("TEST,,, TEST TEST TEST")#=>["TEST", ",", ",", ",", " ", "TEST", " ", "TEST", " ", "TEST"]
```

Works fine. Or I need to refactor my iterator code and spend some time, to get 'clear' result without compact.
Actually, I don't want to spend time on that. But can my approach with compact cause some errors or unexpected output? I've tested it for some time and didn't notice something.
But what would you advice? Is that compact trick dirty and really not good?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All `compact` does is remove nils from your array.  If you are sure you don't want nils in your array, then there shouldn't be any problems.